# Python execute bottom lines first and then top using while

Tags: python, while-loop

My code requires me execute the lines at bottom and then top. 
Here is my code:

```
test = True
while test:
   if test==False:
       print("Now executing top lines of the code")
       break
   elif test==True:
       print("Now executing bottom lines of the code")
       test = False
       continue
```

My expected output:

```
Now executing bottom lines of the code
Now executing top lines of the code
```

Somehow my code is not working. Either it halts printing nothing or goes infinite loop.

Comment: The `test` variable you are using for the conditions is also the one for the loop, so once it goes `False`, the loop exits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
test = True

while True:
    if test==False:
        print("Now executing top lines of the code")
        break
    elif test==True:
        print("Now executing bottom lines of the code")
        test = False
        continue
```

You have such behaviour of code because after first  iteration you set test to False (test = False) and it exits the loop by "while test" (now test is False)  condition. So you never have second iteration of loop